# Open returns (-1) with O_CREAT when file already exists

Tags: c, system-calls

That function saves an unsigned int array in a file. I want it to overwrite an existing file or to create it. If the file doesn't exist, it is filled correctly. If it already exists, it remains as it was : but I want it to be overwritten. That is why I use 'O_CREAT'.

```
int save_pic(t_bunny_pixelarray *pix, const char *filename, t_tekpaint *tekpaint) {
    unsigned int *pixels;
    int FD;
    int i = 0;
    if (!filename)
        return 1;
    if ((FD = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR)) == -1)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

(I write between the last `return 1` and `return 0`).

If I do the following :

```
if ((FD = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR)) == -1) {
    printf("error\n");                                                            
    return 1;
}
```

It prints error if files exists, and doesn't print error if file doesn't exist.
I tried to change `S_IRUSR` to other possible values for I thought maybe the process had no right on the file or something but it doesn't change anything.

It acts like if I was using `O_EXCL`, which I obviously don't.
MUST be a stupid thing.
Thank you.

Comment: What's in `errno` after `open` fails?

Comment: @lurker " EEXIST pathname already exists and O_CREAT and O_EXCL were used." I don't use O_EXCL.

Comment: @melpomene Going to check right now, always forget to do so.

Comment: @melpomene ENAMETOOLONG... Did something stupid before in my program. Thank you and damn me -.-

Comment: @melpomene Hey, is there a way I can close this topic and validate your comment ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`S_IRUSR` means read for user (so without write permission).

The first run the program create the file with permission `-r--------`
The second run fails with EPERM (Permission denied).

You should specify write access :

```
open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IWUSR)
```

or use the default umask using :

```
open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT)
```

Comment: This is true but wasn't the issue. Still +1 cause totally lniked, and useful in this case.